# MSBuild attach to Visual Studio Project Build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, project

I am using [YUICompressor.Net](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/) for minification. The .proj file executes from MSBuild and works fine.

The question is how do I attach the MSBuild action to the build of the main Project?
I know there are some "After Build" events, bud how do I point them to execute my additional MSBuild.

In case it's relevant this is how my MSBuild file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/MsBuild/2003">

<UsingTask TaskName="CssCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="..\bin\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
<UsingTask TaskName="JavaScriptCompressorTask" AssemblyFile="..\bin\Yahoo.Yui.Compressor.Build.MsBuild.dll" />
<Target Name="Minify">
 <ItemGroup>
  <CssFile_Common Include="../Styles/common.css"/>
  <CssFile_Plugins_All Include="../Styles/plugins.all.css"/>
 </ItemGroup>
<CssCompressorTask
      SourceFiles="@(CssFile_Common)"
      DeleteSourceFiles="false"
      OutputFile="../Styles/common.min.css"
      CompressionType="Standard"
      LoggingType="Info"
      PreserveComments="false"
      LineBreakPosition="-1"
   />
  <CssCompressorTask
      SourceFiles="@(CssFile_Plugins_All)"
      DeleteSourceFiles="false"
      OutputFile="../Styles/plugins.all.min.css"
      CompressionType="Standard"
      LoggingType="Info"
      PreserveComments="false"
      LineBreakPosition="-1"
   />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sample file is named Minify.proj you would simply need to put something like this at the bottom of your main project file:

```
  <Import Project="Minify.proj" />

  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="Minify">
  </Target>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I placed suggested above to main .cproj file, Minify.proj file is located in same folder - in root. during build (F6) I just get build succeeded, but nothing happens. Is there any way to trace if "BeforeBuild" Is being called at all? I see from intellisence <Message> tag but it doesn't put anything in output window.